# Is this a JS infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input type='text', and using jQuery, every time this textbox is blurred out, I apply css('background', 'red') to the textbox. The problem is, when I try to debug the code by puttin `alert('test')` and I click OK on the dialog, the same dialog with "test" keeps popping up.

Is this just due to the fact that clicking on OK is considered a blur out of the text box or is it something more serious?
Thanks in advance.

```
$('#input').blur(function(){
       $(this).css('background','red');
       alert('test');
}
```

Comment: use `console.log` for debugging purposes instead it will make it a lot easier on yourself.

Comment: Use `console.log('test')` rather than `alert()`

Comment: Alert _used to be_ a debugging method, but now there are better alternatives. You can use `console.log()`. Every decent browser has a JavaScript console, try pressing F12.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your response. Will try that out. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should debug with the console instead of alerts:

```
$('#input').blur(function(){
       $(this).css('background','red');
       console.log('test');
});
```

I believe in most browsers hitting F12 will bring up the console.

Comment: it may be worth noting that this will throw errors in older versions of internet explorer. fixes can be found pretty easily, though.

Comment: @jbabey Yeah. In practice if it's a temporary statement I just put it in and take it out when I'm done. In a production setting I prepend all my scripts with `var console = {log: function(){}};` which causes all console.log calls to get stripped out during the minification phase. Then they only exist in my development environment, but the live code doesn't have any. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not an infinite loop.
The alert closing simply dispatches the event.

Try using `console.log("test")` instead and watch your browsers console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead

```
$('#input').blur(function(){
       $(this).css('background','red');
       console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/K7Gmy/).

If you get the blur event again and again it sounds like you re-focus the element on blur.

Answer (score 1):

Error in code : `);` missing

```
$('#input').blur(function(){
       $(this).css('background','red');
       alert('test');
});
```

Your code works well.

Comment: What's the difference between your code and OPs (apart from a typo)?

Comment: @SalmanA nothing, but error is error, Though OP's code works well so I tried to find out the error. Thanks..

Comment: The OP mentioned that the alert fires so problem is not the missing `);`, may be he made an error while copying. I didn't -1 by the way.